# Grafana elasticsearch time from now

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I've configured Grafana to use Elasticsearch as a data source and prepared a few panels.
My document in ES index contains only a few fields. It describes some system actions, respectively there are such fields as userId, action date, and others.

Now I faced with the issue that I can't calculate the amount of time left when the action happened. I mean if the action happened 2 days ago, I need to have the number 2 in my table. Pretty simple I supposed.

I couldn't find any metric or transformation that can allow me to do it.

Any suggestion, help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issue with `scripted field`.

In table visualization, I just picked any numeric field, selected `Min` metric, and added script like next:

```
Instant Currentdate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(new Date().getTime()); 
Instant Startdate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['activity'].value.getMillis()); 
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Startdate, Currentdate);
```

As a result, it shows me the number I needed.

I don't find this solution the best, so in case anybody know some better way to resolve this issue, please add a comment.

Comment: Hi! I am trying to do the same. But not sure how and where you wrote this script? Can you share a screenshot?